# How to check on a button click which function was last called out of many custom functions in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

The first method  sets the array of objects in the variable final,the second method sets the array of objects in the variable final1.In this particular save method I want to check in the else condition which method was called last(method1 or method2) so that I can decide which variable should I use inside fetchItemId function?

```
function save(){
  if (final === undefined && final1 !== "")
    fetchItemId(final1);
  if (final1 === undefined && final !== "")
    fetchItemId(final);
  else { 
    // I want to call the last executed method out of 2 
  }
}
```

Comment: you can use a flag and set its value true or false in function calls and check it in else. Declare it as a global variable and set it true inside method1 and false inside method2. Check it in else if it is true last called is method1 , if false last called is method2

Comment: Thank you @SanchitPatiyal-It worked for me..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a flag variable to check this.

Eg

```
var i=0;
method1()
{
//whatever
i=1;
}
method2()
{
//whatever
i=2;
}
```

In your else check value of i.

```
if(i=1)
// method1 was called last
else
if(i=2)
//method2 was called last
else if (i=0)
// none was called
```